# Can I mix character classes in Python RegEx?

Tags: python, regex

Special sequences (character classes) in Python RegEx are escapes like `\w` or `\d` that matches a set of characters.

In my case, I need to be able to match all alpha-numerical characters except numbers.

That is, `\w` minus `\d`.

I need to use the special sequence `\w` because I'm dealing with **non-ASCII** characters and need to match symbols like "Æ" and "Ø".

One would think I could use this expression: `[\w^\d]` but it doesn't seem to match anything and I'm not sure why.

So in short, how can I mix (add/subtract) special sequences in Python Regular Expressions?

---

**EDIT**: I accidentally used `[\W^\d]` instead of `[\w^\d]`. The latter does indeed match something, including parentheses and commas which are not alpha-numerical characters as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: your expression matches alpha, numbers, and ^, i think. ^ for negating a class should be placed at the begining of the class definition

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `r"[^\W\d]"`, ie. invert the union of non-alphanumerics and numbers.

Comment: Note that you need to set `re.UNICODE` for this to match `æ` and other non-ASCII characters. The OP probably already does this, but it bears stating.

Comment: In this case, how do I add specific characters to the character class, e.g. spaces or commas?

Comment: @Codemonkey You can use a non-capturing group and `|`: `(?:[^\W\d]|[, ])`

Answer (score 9):

You cannot subtract character classes, no.

Your best bet is to use the [`regex` project](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which offers additional functionality while remaining backwards compatible with the `re` module in in the standard library. It supports character classes based on Unicode properties:

```
\p{IsAlphabetic}
```

This will match any character that the Unicode specification states is an alphabetic character.

Even better, `regex` *does* support character class subtraction; it views such classes as sets and allows you to create a difference with the `--` operator:

```
[\w--\d]
```

matches everything in `\w` except anything that also matches `\d`.

Comment: Is the `regex` package still set to replace the built-in `re` module? The built-in module is powerful enough for most basic tasks while still being relatively simple to use. The `regex` module is indeed incomparably powerful for all kinds of tasks but the power comes with a price. I hope that such specialized tools will stay independent. For everyone's benefit.

Comment: @Jeyekomon: No, in the interim the [project has dropped the intention to replace the `re` module](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/commit/47ec54e6ff40afabb3d647c7cd83d35c1d199086). I've updated the wording in my answer to match.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude classes using a negative lookahead assertion, such as `r'(?!\d)[\w]'` to match a word character, excluding digits. For example:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?!\d)[\w]', '12bac')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7779218>
>>> _.group(0)
'b'
```

To exclude more than one group, you can use the usual `[...]` syntax in the lookahead assertion, for example `r'(?![0-5])[\w]'` would match any alphanumeric character except for digits 0-5.

As with `[...]`, the above construct matches a single character. To match multiple characters, add a repetition operator:

```
>>> re.search(r'((?!\d)[\w])+', '12bac15')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f44cd2588a0>
>>> _.group(0)
'bac'
```

Comment: This only works for one-letter combos; you'd have to group this in a larger group to work at all.

Comment: Sure, but that's the case with [...] matching as well. I'll update the answer to state it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly combine (boolean and) character sets in a single regex, whether one is negated or not. Otherwise you could simply have combined `[^\d]` and `\w`.

Note: the `^` has to be at the start of the set, and applies to the whole set. From the docs: "If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters that are not in the set will be matched.". 
Your set `[\w^\d]` tries to match an alpha-numerical character, followed by a caret, followed by a digit. I can imagine that doesn't match anything either.

I would do it in two steps, effectly combining the regular expressions. First match by non-digits (inner regex), then match by alpha-numerical characters:

```
re.search('\w+', re.search('([^\d]+)', s).group(0)).group(0)
```

or variations to this theme.

Note that would need to surround this with a `try: except:` block, as it will throw an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` in case one of the two regexes fails. But you can, of course, split this single line up in a few more lines.