# python re any unicode word except if it contains digits

Tags: python, regex

I need to match a string of words such as `"Miguel Tiago"`, but do not want strings that may contain numbers. For example I do not want strings such as `"Miguel10 Tiago"`. Also all strings may contain unicode.

I can't simple do:

```
re.match(ur'^[a-zA-Z ]+',string,re.UNICODE)
```

because for such case words with unicode such as 'ç' won't be recognized.

How can I use the rule `[\w ]+` and exclude the digits?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?:[^\W\d]|\s)+', s, re.UNICODE)`

Comment: Actually, it is a dupe. `r'(?:(?!\d)[\w ])+'` will also work for you, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12349464/3832970).

Comment: But that case it will return for the example `Miguel10 Tiago` the list `['Miguel','Tiago']`, which is something I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you are looking for is: `(([^\W\d]+(?![\w\d])\s?)+)`

Comment: Thanks and sorry but I need to edit the question to me more clear.

Comment: Ok, I edit the question. Also added a detail I forgot to put, which the need to recognize more that one word.

Comment: Surely in this case you could just do something with the `\D` (not digit) character class. Just to be clear, you don't want it to be able to include symbols just unicode characters.

Comment: I believe this should work: `([^\W\d]+(?![\w\d]))`. Let me know and I will write it up properly with an explanation.

This for multiple words: `(([^\W\d]+(?![\w\d]))\s)*`

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. The only thing now is that the multiple words is not working: `re.match(ur'(([^\W\d]+(?![\w\d]))\s)*',u'Miguel Tiago',re.UNICODE).group()` gives `Miguel `

Comment: Try `(([^\W\d]+(?![\w\d])\s?)+)` realised that you need to specify that there may or may not be a space after it.

Comment: I've realised there is a flaw in this, that if the numbers appear within the word this won't work as expected